# Obtener CSV: origen datos lista con atributos, uno de los cuales es otra lista con mas atributos y otra lista

Tags: c#, csv

Mi objetivo es obtener un CSV, (en los que habrá muchos datos repetidos) con un objeto que tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
public class Consulta
{
    public string Empresa { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Pedido> ListaPedidos { get; set; }
}
public class Pedido
{
    public int Id_pedido { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Especialidad> ListaEspecialidades { get; set; }
}
public class Especialidad
{
    public int Id_especialidad { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Trabajador> ListaTrabajadores { get; set; }
}
public class Trabajador
{
    public int Id_trabajador { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Para llegar al detalle de `Trabajadores`, habrá que repetir muchos datos, eso no importa.

He probado a usar `ChoETL`, `CsvHelper`... ahora mismo estoy investigando reflection, pero no consigo que se repitan las cabeceras cuando accedo al segundo nivel.
La salida deseada seria algo así:[image: TBLON DE DATOS]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Yo personalmente no entiendo bien tu pregunta. Podrías pulsar en [edit] y tratar de explicar mejor cual es tu problema, y que has intentado para solucionarlo? Un saludo y bienvenido de nuevo

Comment: de donde salen las columnas de `fecha_inicio` y `fecha_fin` si estas no estan en ningun propiedad de las clases que defines?

Comment: Las clases tienen mas propiedades, pero para no cargar la consulta las he reducido, perdon.(son campos de la clase consulta)

Comment: @Leandro:        Muchas gracias por responder. Lo que necesito es no tener que definir la clase resultante al aplanar, es decir, que el código detecte el tipo de propiedades de un objeto, que las lea, y cuando detecta que hay otro objeto dentro, cree uno de ese tipo, y vuelva a realizar el ciclo.Tengo esta necesidad por que se puede dar el caso de objetos sin datos, por ejemplo, un pedido sin especialidades, o especialidades sin trabajadores.O que haya que añadir o quitar un campo. Intentar crear un código que sea cual sea la estructura que reciba sea capaz de realizar el aplanamiento.

Comment: ejemplo(muy pobre:)private void DoRecursive(object obj)
        {            
            Type type = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] pi = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi){
                label1.Text += p.Name;
                if (p.PropertyType.IsClass && !p.PropertyType.IsValueType && !p.PropertyType.IsPrimitive && p.PropertyType.FullName != "System.String")
                {               
                    object new_obj = new object();//este objeto deberia de ser del tipo que hemos obtenido
                    DoRecursive(new_obj); }}

Comment: Pero el excel no es dinamico, este tienes un nro definido de columnas que puedes ponerles datos a las celdas o no segun el objeto, pero cada columna mapea con una propidad simple o completa determinada, no le veo ningun sentido hacer todo tan dinamico cunado el excel no lo es. si puede agregar validaciones por si el dato no tiene valor poneidno un vacio o valor por defecto, pero es validacion.

Answer (score 0):

Mas alla de tener una estructura jerarquica de objeto quizas para generar el `csv` seria recomendable desnormalizar y aplanar los datos para exportarlos, podrias ayudarte con `linq`

Defines la clase con las columnas que quieres exportar

```
public class csvData
{
    public string Empresa { get; set; }
    public int Id_pedido { get; set; }
    public int Id_especialidad { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
}
```

linq te ayuda a aplanar los datos

```
var result = from empresa in empresaList
             from pedido in empresa.ListaPedidos
             from especialidad in pedido.ListaEspecialidades 
             select new csvData(){
                 Empresa = empresa.Empresa,
                 Id_pedido = pedido.Id_pedido,
                 Id_especialidad = especialidad.Id_especialidad,
                 Numero = especualidad.Numero
             }
```

Entonces lo que exportas al excel es la clase que aplana los datos compatible con una tabla de excel